# How do pencil erasers erase on a fundamental level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrostatics, atomic-physics, everyday-life, material-science

One could say we're taking advantage of friction, but I want to dig deeper down to atomic level: what's the process or chain that happens when one erases?

Edit: subatomic -> atomic

Comment: Subatomic? There is nothing different between the nuclei of an eraser and anything else with similar atoms. The subatomic level is too small. Pencil writing and erasing doesn’t occur at that level

Answer (score 3):

The eraser has a certain amount of "gumminess" which allows it to stick to things like fine dust. Pencil marks on paper consist of graphite dust pushed down into the fibrous surface of the paper. Rubbing an eraser against pencil on paper gets the dust to stick to and get rolled up into the topmost surface of the eraser. More scrubbing with the eraser peels off the topmost surface of the eraser and exposes more fresh, gummy surface and as long as you keep rubbing, the eraser erodes away and carries off the graphite marks.

Comment: But at a smaller scale, how does the graphite dust stick to the paper surface in the first place? Same for that very graphite dust sticking to an eraser.

Comment: @damacc From Chem Stack Exchange: London Forces: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24007/how-are-pencil-marks-adhered-to-the-paper

Comment: @DKNguyen do erasers work in other cities as well?

Comment: @JuanPerez At least 29 cities are named London, so at least that many.